# Speeding up similarity function using numpy and parallel processing?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I've got a matrix of points (real shape is generally in the neighborhood of (8000,127000)):

`M = [[1,10,2],[10,2,2],[8,3,4],[2,1,9]]`

And a target:

`N = [1,2,10]`

I'm using this function to create an array of distances from N (which I then sort by distance):

```
similarity_scores = M.dot(N)/ (np.linalg.norm(M, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(N))
```

Which depending on the shape of M can be very fast or take upwards of a second or two.  I'm using this for live search where I am creating N on the fly.

Is there a way I can split up M and parallel process this function to gain speed? From my experience so far, multiprocessing requires loading a lot of data just to run the processes in parallel... Not something that seems to work on an on demand type function.

Comment: `M` is a square n-by-n matrix, and `N` is a vector of length `n`. Correct?

Comment: What is `(8,000,127,000)`?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer that is correct

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is the typical shape of M sometimes it is less rows (600,127,000) depending on the number of intersections I find in my initial search... I just saw the reason for the confusion it should read (8000,127000)

Comment: @NicoSchlömer maybe I misinterpreted, it is not always a "square" n by n matrix, sometimes it is a rectangle... very unlikely to be a square actually

Comment: The size of your matrix is inpossible. Please be more accurate about it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your exact needs are, you may want to consider an alternate data structure. If you are searching for something like the `k` nearest neighbors to a given `N`, you might consider using [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html):

```
tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(M)
```

You can then obtain the `k` nearest distances to a given `N` using [`query`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query):

```
dist = tree.query(N, k=10)
```

For a set of 3D points, this will be much faster than doing a brute-force search like you are proposing. However, for dimensions in the thousands (really anything >10 or so), it's unlikely that you will get any speedup at all from a KDTree.